# Testing list equivalency by including properties in nested lists using Fluent Assertions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

Is there a way to assert the equivalency of two lists of objects by properties located in a nested list? I know you can test equivalency with ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo() and Include() only certain properties, but I would like to call Include() on a property defined in a nested list:

```cs
class A
{
    public B[] List { get; set; }
    public string SomePropertyIDontCareAbout { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string PropertyToInclude { get; set; }
    public string SomePropertyIDontCareAbout { get; set; }
}

var list1 = new[]
{
    new A
    {
        List = new[] {new B(), new B()}
    },
};
var list2 = new[]
{
    new A
    {
        List = new[] {new B(), new B()}
    },
};

list1.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(list2, options => options
    .Including(o => o.List.Select(l => l.PropertyToInclude))); // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there isn't an idiomatic way to achieve this, but the API is flexible enough to do it, albeit in a more clumpsy way.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/500) about this problem, which also lists some solutions.

With the current API (version 5.7.0), your posted example can be asserted by only including the property `List`, and then excluding properties ending with `"SomePropertyIDontCareAbout"`.

```cs
var list1 = new[]
{
    new A
    {
        SomePropertyIDontCareAbout = "FOO",
        List = new[]
        {
            new B()
            {
                PropertyToInclude = "BAR",
                SomePropertyIDontCareAbout = "BAZ"
            },
        }
    },
};

var list2 = new[]
{
    new A
    {
        SomePropertyIDontCareAbout = "BOOM",
        List = new[]
        {
            new B()
            {
                PropertyToInclude = "BAR",
                SomePropertyIDontCareAbout = "BOOM"
            },
        }
    },
};

// Assert
list1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(list2, opt => opt
    .Including(e => e.List)
    .Excluding(e => e.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith(nameof(B.SomePropertyIDontCareAbout))));
```